# What is my mistake in setting CLASSPATH?

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I installed Netbeans and JDK1.7.0_40 in following directory

```
Netbeans:
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2

JDK path:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\
```

Next I tried to do the CLASSPATH thing following this website:
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-the-Java-Software-Development-Kit

Under System Variable, I scroll to the end of PATH and added (without deleting anything)

```
;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\
```

But at command prompt when I type javac, it tells me

```
javac not recognized as internal or external...
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: you should point to the /bin folder in the jdk folder

Answer (score 2):

You want another path and it is this one :)

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `bin` to the end of the Java path...

`;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin`

`javac` lives in the bin directory...

Comment: Just have a query "bin is inside jdk then why it is not searched" ? Is it classpath is restricted to a folder and not its subfolders ?

Comment: First, it's not the classpath you are trying to change, it's the OS search path, the two are different. one is used by the OS and one is used by Java.  When you try and execute `javac`, the OS uses the `PATH` variable to search for the command by appending `javac` to each element in the `PATH`, therefore, when the OS looks in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\`, it won't find `javac`, but when it looks in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin` it will.

Comment: Yes.  Subfolders are not searched.

Comment: The `classpath` is used by Java to find classes, libraries and other resources at compile and run time. `PATH` is used by the OS to find commands on your disk...

Comment: So PATH will not search Subfolders; And classpath will search subfolders, is it? Good! Thanks! +1

Comment: No, neither will search sub folders ;)